# How do I get these two buttons on the bottom of my program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

Write a program that displays two buttons labeled “Green” and “Orange”.

If the user clicks on the green button, the background of the window changes to green. If the user clicks on the orange button, the background of the window changes to Orange.

Create a `JFrame` for this GUI. The GUI employs the default layout manager. A `JPanel` is needed.

Place the two buttons inside the panel and add the panel to the south region of the border layout.

Notice the text in the title bar. The green button should have white text and a green background. The orange button should have black text with an orange background.

Below is what I have so far, it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class LabAssign91 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JPanel loc1Panel;
private JButton greenButton, orangeButton;

public LabAssign91()
{
    super("Colored Buttons");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    setSize(300,250);
    setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(loc1Panel);
    loc1Panel = new JPanel();
    add(loc1Panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    greenButton = new JButton("Green");
    greenButton.addActionListener(this);
    loc1Panel.add(greenButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    greenButton.setBackground(Color.green);;
    orangeButton = new JButton("Orange");
    orangeButton.addActionListener(this);
    loc1Panel.add(orangeButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    orangeButton.setBackground(Color.orange);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LabAssign91 app = new LabAssign91();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

}

Comment: *"it doesnt seem to work."*  What did you expect to see?  What happened instead?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This doesn't really meet the guidelines for posting questions, as described in the [FAQ] and [Ask].  Just posting the code skeleton and asking for someone to finish it for you is not the right approach.  Try to actually write the necessary code yourself and then ask a specific question when you hit a problem.

Comment: You changed the "default" layout from `BorderLayout` to `setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));`, which I'm pretty sure you're assignment said not to do ;).  Also, you're not creating `loc1Panel` before adding it ... the first time, which in of itself is weird (adding twice)

Comment: I wanted two buttons side by side on the bottom, but they either seem to overlap or disappear no matter what I do.

Answer (score 3):

I have used `BorderLayout` for the `JFrame` and `FlowLayout` for the `ButtonPanel`. `ButtonPanel` is the bottom panel of the frame.

[image]

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.add(new JLabel("Top Panel"));

middlepanel = new JPanel();
middlepanel.add(new JLabel("Middle Panel"));

bottomPanel = new JPanel();

bottomPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Orange"));
bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Green"));

frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(middlepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for a JFrame is BorderLayout which has a SOUTH constraint. So there is no need for this statement.

```
//setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
```

The default layout for a JPanel is a FlowLayout. So the following statements do nothing:

```
loc1Panel.add(greenButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
loc1Panel.add(orangeButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). There is a section on using a BorderLayout and on using a FlowLayout. I don't know if you are supposed to use just panels with a BorderLayout or panels with a combination of BorderLayout and FlowLayout. I'll let you fix the code to meet your requirement.

Comment: Okay I actually got it working now. Whenever I click the orange button though, it only changes the background color to orange on the bottom of the screen. My code is loc1Panel. setBackground(Color.orange);

Comment: @user2288575 Stop changing the color of the button panel and try changing the color of the frame's content pane instead

Comment: (ps - The OP's assignment was to add the buttons to the south ;))